# Cloudflare IPV6 Gateway with a Dyn IP via Dyndns

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, ipv6, ipv4

Firstly Apologies if this has already been asked or resolved.

My question is this.

Is it possible to use a domain from dynv6.com say xyz.dynv6.com and then get cloudflare to do the ipv6 / ipv4 automatic gateway which they offer.

Essentially i have a IPv6 address which is publicly accessible but my IPv4 isnt (Virgin Media Ireland)

i can then host what ever i wanted to on my machine and this would allow anybody (IPv4 and IPv6) users to access it.

i have a pfSense firewall running on a VM hosted on this machine so in future i'd want to make that IPv6 Address the public one and then have rules in place to forward to the machines behind the firewall.

Do you guys know if this is possible or can you advise on perhaps an alternative method to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CloudFlare in front of an IPv6-only web site, you only need to add an AAAA record for your host in the DNS records, and don't add an A record. CloudFlare will provide service on both IPv4 and IPv6, but will only contact your server on IPv6. But you can't use someone else's domain on CloudFlare; you would have to purchase your own.

Comment: Wow! Really that simple?

Comment: Again, you can't use a subdomain of someone else's domain. So you couldn't use their .eu5.net domain, because it's theirs and not registered to you.

Comment: Right okay, sorry I only quickly googled free domains so didn't spot it.Thanks again